# How do I configure remote host journal.conf file with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I am trying to configure raspberry pi journalctl using ansible.
I tried using some ansible-galaxy roles which seem too complicated and did not deliver in the end.

I am just trying to configure the /etc/systemd/journald.conf file.

Can I do it with ansible.builtin.systemd or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a playbook and a template file.

- myproject/changejournald.yml # your playbook
- myproject/journald.conf.j2 # a jinja2 template, the 'journald.conf as you want it'

in changejournald.yml

```
---
- name: upload new template
  template:
   src: 'journald.conf.j2'
   dest: '/etc/systemd/journald.conf'
  become: true #<-- unless you are connecting as root

- name: reload systemd-journald
  systemd:
   name: systemd-journald
   state: restart 
  become: true
```

Something like that should work?

There are also other modules like lineinfile or blockinfile that might be more useful depending on how you intend to configure it.

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253203/how-to-tell-journald-to-re-read-its-configuration